# Export CSV from CartoDB with lat and lon?

Tags: carto, latitude-longitude

If you create a point dataset in CartoDB then export it to CSV, you get a "the_geom" column in the WKB format. How do you get individual `lat` and `lon` columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since CartoDB uses PostGIS, you can use PostGIS functions:

1. On the SQL tab (Map View), modify the default query to look something like this:

`SELECT *,
ST_X(the_geom) AS lon,
ST_Y(the_geom) AS lat
FROM mytable`

2. Under "Edit" select "Export Layer" and choose CSV.

Comment: If the geom is a polygon, you can export the lat and lon using this:  ST_X(ST_Centroid(the_geom)) and ST_Y(ST_Centroid(the_geom))